# Power series/inhomogenous differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

Looking at a method to solve the inhomogenous differential equation $$y'-ty=t^2 $$

Assuming that the power series $\sum_{n=0}^n c_n t^n$ has a convergence radius $\rho > 0$. $$y(t) = \sum_{n=0}^n c_n t^n$$

How can I determine $a_0,a_1,a_2...$ so that  $y'-ty = \sum_{n=0}^n a_n t^n$ for all $t \in]-\rho,\rho[$ ???

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A power series solution can be easily obtained. Making $y=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k t^k$ and substituting into the ODE we have

$$
\left(\sum_{k=0}^n a_k t^k\right)'-t\left(\sum_{k=0}^n a_k t^k\right)-t^2=0
$$

after grouping for powers of $t$ we have

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 a_1&=&0 \\
 2 a_2-a_0&=&0 \\
 3 a_3-a_1 &=&1 \\
 4 a_4-a_2&=&0 \\
 5 a_5-a_3&=&0 \\
 6 a_6-a_4&=&0 \\
 7 a_7-a_5&=&0 \\
 8 a_8-a_6&=&0 \\
 9 a_9-a_7&=&0 \\
 10 a_{10}-a_8&=&0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots
\end{array}
\right.
$$

solving for $n=10$ we obtain

$$
y_{10} = a_0\left(1+\frac{t^2}{2}+\frac{t^4}{8}+\frac{t^6}{48}+\frac{t^8}{384}+\frac{t^{10}}{3840}\right)+\frac{t^3}{3}+\frac{t^5}{15}+\frac{t^7}{105}+\frac{t^9}{945}+O\left(t^{11}\right)
$$

Follows a plot showing in blue the closed solution for $y(0)=1$ as well as in red the series approximation for $a_0=1$.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a faster way to proceed : \begin{aligned}y'-ty&=t^{2}\\ \iff \left(y'-ty\right)\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{t^{2}}{2}}&=t^{2}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{t^{2}}{2}}\\ \iff \ \ \ \ \  \left(y\,\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{t^{2}}{2}}\right)'&=t^{2}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{t^{2}}{2}}\\ \iff \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ y\,\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{t^{2}}{2}}&=\int{t^{2}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{t^{2}}{2}}\,\mathrm{d}t}+C \end{aligned}

Answer (score 0):

That is a [linear differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation) of the first order, thus solvable. The solution  to the homogeneous equation goes as follows:

$\begin{align*}
  y' - t y
    &= 0 \\
  \frac{y'}{y}
    &= t \\
  \ln y = \frac{t^2}{2} + \ln c \\
  y
    &= c e^{t^2 / 2}
\end{align*}$

To find a particular solution to the non-homogeneous equation, divide throughout by any solution to the homogeneous equation:

$\begin{align*}
  y' e^{- t^2 / 2} - y t e^{- t^2 / 2}
     &= t e^{- t^2 / 2} \\
  \frac{d}{d t} \left( y e^{- t^2 / 2} \right)
     &= t^2 e^{- t^2 / 2}
\end{align*}$

Integrate, and you are done:

$\begin{align*}
  y e^{-t^2 / 2}
     &= \int t^2 e^{-t^2 / 2} d t
\end{align*}$

This doesn't have a elementary antiderivative.